# onClick event badly managed with three recyclerviews

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm displaying three recyclerviews inside a fragment. I have recently changed my implementation so I can display some feature on a dropdown menu while long pressing on an item inside one of the three recyclerview.

Since then my app treats the click event on the two first recyclerview incorrectly (out of bound issue) and I know from debbuging that those click events are managed onely by the third adapter.

Here's my fragment code displaying the three recyclerviews:

```java
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private int Index;

    private ForecastRecyclerAdapter FirstView_Adapter;
    private ForecastRecyclerAdapter SecondView_Adapter;
    private ForecastRecyclerAdapter ThirdView_Adapter;

    private CardView FirstCard, SecondCard, ThirdCard;
    private LinearLayout SeparatorLayout1, SeparatorLayout2;

    private ArrayList<MainViewArrayListRecycler> ListFirstView;
    private ArrayList<MainViewArrayListRecycler> ListSecondView;
    private ArrayList<MainViewArrayListRecycler> ListThirdView;

    public static ActivityFragment newInstance(int Index) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        ActivityFragment fragment = new ActivityFragment();
        args.putInt(GETINDEX, Index);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainactivity_forecast, container, false);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            Index = getArguments().getInt(GETINDEX);
        }

        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getInfo().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), Informations -> {
            if (Informations != null) {
                FillUpArray(Informations.get(Index));
            }
        });

        FirstCard = mview.findViewById(R.id.FirstCard);
        SecondCard = mview.findViewById(R.id.SecondCard);
        ThirdCard = mview.findViewById(R.id.ThirdCard);

        SeparatorLayout1 = mview.findViewById(R.id.SeparatorLayout1);
        SeparatorLayout2 = mview.findViewById(R.id.SeparatorLayout2);

        RecyclerView FirstView = mview.findViewById(R.id.First_Inside_Recycler);
        RecyclerView SecondView = mview.findViewById(R.id.Second_Inside_Recycler);
        RecyclerView ThirdView = mview.findViewById(R.id.Third_Inside_Recycler);

        FirstView_Adapter = new ForecastRecyclerAdapter();
        SecondView_Adapter = new ForecastRecyclerAdapter();
        ThirdView_Adapter = new ForecastRecyclerAdapter();

        FirstView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        SecondView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        ThirdView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        FirstView.setAdapter(FirstView_Adapter);
        SecondView.setAdapter(SecondView_Adapter);
        ThirdView.setAdapter(ThirdView_Adapter);

        FirstView_Adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ActivityFragmentAdapter.ActivityFragmentAdapterListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFirstClick(int position) {

                //...

            }

            @Override
            public void onSecondClick(int position) {

                //...

            }

            @Override
            public void onThirdClick(int position, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {

                    //...

                }

            }
        });

        SecondView_Adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ActivityFragmentAdapter.ActivityFragmentAdapterListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFirstClick(int position) {

                //...

            }

            @Override
            public void onSecondClick(int position) {

                //...

            }

            @Override
            public void onThirdClick(int position, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {

                    //...

                }
            }
        });

        ThirdView_Adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ActivityFragmentAdapter.ActivityFragmentAdapterListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFirstClick(int position) {

               //...

            }

            @Override
            public void onSecondClick(int position) {

                //...

            }

            @Override
            public void onThirdClick(int position, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {

                    //...

                }

            }
        });

        return mview;
    }

    private void FillUpArray(Information Info) {

        /* Fill up the different arraylist and call setData frome the adapter */
      
    }

}
```

Here's the recycler adapter class used:

```java
public class ActivityFragmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActivityFragmentAdapter.InsideRecyclerHolder> {

    private ArrayList<MainViewArrayListRecycler> mRecyclerArrayListType;
    private static ActivityFragmentAdapterListener mListener;

    private String mUnit;
    private int mAverageDistance;
    private int mCurrentDistance;
    private int mPeriodInterval;

    public void setData(ArrayList<MainViewArrayListRecycler> RecyclerArrayListType) {

        mRecyclerArrayListType = RecyclerArrayListType;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public InsideRecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View myOwnView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast_recycler, parent, false);

        return new InsideRecyclerHolder(myOwnView, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InsideRecyclerHolder holder, int position) {
        MainViewArrayListRecycler currentItem = mRecyclerArrayListType.get(position);

        String tmpConcatDistance;

        holder.t1.setText(currentItem.getTitle()));
        holder.t2.setText(currentItem.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRecyclerArrayListType.size();
    }

    public static class InsideRecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener{
        final TextView t1;
        final TextView t2;
        final CheckBox cb1;

        public InsideRecyclerHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final ForecastRecyclerAdapterListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            t1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            t2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
            cb1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb1);

            cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getBindingAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onThirdClick(position, isChecked);
                        cb1.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getBindingAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case 1:
                            mListener.onFirstClick(position);
                            return true;
                        case 2:
                            mListener.onSecondClick(position);
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.dropdown_menu_title);
            MenuItem firstItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, R.string.dropdown_menu_firstItem);
            MenuItem secondItem = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, R.string.dropdown_menu_secondItem);

            firstItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            secondItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

    }

    public interface ActivityFragmentAdapterListener {
        void onFirstClick(int position);
        void onSecondClick(int position);
        void onThirdClick(int position, boolean isChecked);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ActivityFragmentAdapterListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

}
```

What can be the issue ?

Comment: What is the actual exception and stack trace?

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.main, PID: 8471
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at com.main.ActivityFragment$3.onThirdClick(ForecastRecycler.java:180)
        at com.main.ActivityFragmentAdapter$InsideRecyclerHolder.lambda$new$0$ActivityFragmentAdapter$InsideRecyclerHolder(ForecastRecyclerAdapter.java:106)
        at com.main.adapter.-$$Lambda$ActivityFragmentAdapter$InsideRecyclerHolder$e4GJp3J47o-DLi5iEH2vyzImvk8.onCheckedChanged(lambda)`

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to read from an empty ArrayList somewhere in the redacted code in one of the 3 overridden onThirdClick in if(isChecked). Can't be more exact, since you didn't share that part of the code.
@Override
            public void onThirdClick(int position, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {

                    //...

                }
            }

Comment: I actually solved my issue by removing the static attribute of the listener of my adapter class